# attempt to call method "GetPosition" (a nil value)

Tags: lua

Программа самая простая, но ошибку `attempt to call method "GetPosition" (a nil value)` не получается исправить.

```
Script.respawnPoint = "" -- entity "Respawn point"

function Script:Collision(entity, position, normal, speed)
  if(entity:GetKeyValue("name") == "Player1") then
    spawnPos = self.respawnPoint:GetPosition()
    entity:SetPosition(spawnPos)
  end
end
```

Comment: Ну так ведь у строки нету такого метода. Укажите, какую библиотеку используйте и перечитайте свой гайд внимательно.

Answer (score 0):

Функции `GetPosition` для `self.respawnPoint` не существует. 
Возможно `self.respawnPoint` - это уже нужная вам позиция.